# How to get search results from Google with Java or C#?

Tags: c#, java

I want to use google search in my application (including options of getting specific results like: 'results only from the last day').

How can I do that?

Comment: I just didn't find in google's custom api that option i've wrote

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use Google Custom Search API

https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview